# Words Within Words

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a second word which is contained in the first word, as in, for example, the word *end* in the word *friend*?

Comment: No. You can talk about letter strings as being part of larger letter strings, but letter strings are not words.

Comment: I think forms like [abso-bloody-lutely](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abso+bloody+lutely) (which has its own dictionary definition there) are called "infixes". There must be something subtle going on, because nobody *ever* says "ab-bloody-solutely".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - That is called [tmesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmesis). It says: " The insertion may occur between the parts of a compound word, or between **syllable boundaries (dystmesis)**, but always preceding a **stressed syllable** (e.g. one would never say, "Ab-bloody-solutely", preferring "Abso-bloody-lutely")."

Comment: They're a subset of 'hidden words' and constitute one type of cryptic crossword clue.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up with is "**[subword](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/Scrabble+and+retrograde+analysis-a0263880621)**":

> A subword of a word is a sequence of at least 2 letters obtainable by removing (possibly zero) letters from the beginning and end; it is proper if at least one letter is removed.

Though this concept is simply mentioned regarding to word games mainly, it even branches out to mathematical and computational linguistics. It is considered as substring and subsequence in some of the cases as well.

This concept is mentioned in compound structures and agglutination also.